# Error in building CGAL example Triangulation_2

Tags: cgal

I installed CGAL and tried to follow manual, but I failed to build example Triangulation_2. I used terminal in mac and run the code.

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/draw_triangulation_2.dir/draw_triangulation_2.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/janeh/Downloads/CGAL-5.0.2/examples/Triangulation_2/draw_triangulation_2.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/draw_triangulation_2.h:16:10: fatal error: 
      'CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h' file not found
#include <CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/draw_triangulation_2.dir/draw_triangulation_2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/draw_triangulation_2.dir/all] Error 2
```

I checked `Basic_viewer_qt.h` and it is at the right location

```
/Users/janeh/Downloads/CGAL-5.0.2/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h
```

But somehow `draw_triangulation_2.h` can't include it. Is there any reason why this happens?

Comment: You seem to have 2 versions of CGAL, one in /usr/local and one in your home?

Comment: I think `/usr/local/include/CGAL` is a location of its installation, and in my home it is a example file I downloaded from https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/usage.html

Comment: I just checked `/usr/local` and found out I missing Qt folder there! Thank you for your advice:)

Comment: You won't have the necessary files for graphical examples with the brew version.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check what I'm missing.